# iOS 7 keep buttons at bottom in 3.5inch and 4inch

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I haven't done iOS development in a while (since Xcode 4 and iOS 5). And I have a very noobish question:

How can I keep buttons at the bottom of a storyboard viewcontroller on both 3.5inch and 4 inch devices? Previously I could use 'origin' or something similar in the right side panel.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bxTfiHM.png]

Comment: I think this might be answered somewhere? Have you found anything while researching?

Comment: You can do this programmatically like this: if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height<568)
{
     // Set button frames for 3.5 inch screen
}
else
{
     // Set button frames for 4.0 inch screen
}

Comment: You can directly also write like this btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 100, 80, 30); // Set bottom margin as per your requirement in place of 100.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick solution, especially if you don't need to deal with rotation of elements much is to add some basic auto layout constraints to your view.

Once you have your button set in place in your view where you want it to stay in the view, select your View in the Storyboard and then from the Menu Select Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Constraints -> Add Missing Constraints in View.

Simply doing that will give you what you want.  Make sure you have auto layout enabled for your storyboard.

Comment: Constraints would be a overkill IMO in this case. If he just needs stuff to stick to the bottom, just use autoresizing masks.

Comment: It's literally 3 button clicks.  I'm not sure that qualifies as overkill.

Answer (score 4):

set autoresizing mask as shown in image to keep button at buttom in both 3.5 and 4.
[image: set autosizing mask]

Answer (score 3):

i think you are using autolayout so apply first approach

with AutoLayout. add constrains for your widgets

[image]

without AutoLayout

[image]